# Create multiple circle linear loading bar in react-native

Tags: react-native, animation, progress-bar

As my requirement is showing loading bar same as attached image
[image]

In the center i need icon and all three line animate in different direction(eg. yellow will rotate clockwise, red will anti clockwise and orange will clockwise)

I have done searching many where but i did not find same as.

Also any one can provide me NPM library if there

Thanks